# How can i get node by use class name inside for loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is the full code my problem on js code when i try to use by calling class name inside loop it's not work i do not understand why i variable not return 0 when i click on first accordion it return 3.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    /*
     * var panel = this.nextElementSibling; 
     *it works but i want to get panel by classname
     */
    panel = document.getElementsByClassName("panel")[i];
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend `post.body.text = post.body.text.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Please do not SHOUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stackoverflow.

So, answering your question, its not working because your loop counter i variable is not scoped.

Its being [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Hoisting) to the global scope of your code, and it will always have the value 3 because its the value that has when the loop ends.

to solve this problem you only have to do this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
   //your code
}
```

when you use let or const your variable is scoped. [let document](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)